# Import non-contiguous cell range from Excel to an R object

Tags: r, xlconnect

Does anyone know of a function that could import non-contiguous cells from *MS Excel* into one *R object* in a simple way? That is, a function that would take a non-contiguous cell range (e.g.  *'A1:B10,D1:C10'*) in a given Excel worksheet as an input, and return an *R object* (e.g. numeric vector). `readNamedRegion()` from the *XLConnect* package does not work with non-contiguous cell ranges and using `appendNamedRegion()` would introduce unwanted complexity in my code.

Comment: You can use readWorksheet with the region argument in a vectorized manner (i.e. one readWorksheet call with region being the vector of regions to read in). This should provide what you are looking for if I understand you correctly. You may then use rbind on the result ...